# Why extracting zip file is also giving me folder name before file?

Tags: python

'''

```
def extract_files_from_zip(files):
   for file in files:
      with ZipFile(file) as zip:
          extract_file_names = zip.namelist()
        
   return extract_file_names

extracted_files = extract_files_from_zip(full_path)
print(extracted_files)
```

'''

the output of the file look like this

['Excel/', 'Excel/AP26113_1001_ADaM Spec & Data_QC Issue Log.xlsx', 'Excel/pinnacle21-report-2021-03-10T11-32-34-919.xlsx', 'Excel/TAK13DDI-26113D Trial Design.xlsm', 'Excel/TAK13DDI-26113D_SDTM_Metadata_2021-02-06T19-09-32.xlsx', 'Excel/TAK13DDI_SDTM_DMT_Appendix.xlsx']

I don't want 'Excel/' in my list, What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you are looking for: (Here a is the output list that got)

```py
a = ['Excel/', 'Excel/AP26113_1001_ADaM Spec & Data_QC Issue Log.xlsx', 'Excel/pinnacle21-report-2021-03-10T11-32-34-919.xlsx',
     'Excel/TAK13DDI-26113D Trial Design.xlsm', 'Excel/TAK13DDI-26113D_SDTM_Metadata_2021-02-06T19-09-32.xlsx', 'Excel/TAK13DDI_SDTM_DMT_Appendix.xlsx']
b = [i[6::] for i in a]
print(b)
```

Output:

```py
['', 'AP26113_1001_ADaM Spec & Data_QC Issue Log.xlsx', 'pinnacle21-report-2021-03-10T11-32-34-919.xlsx', 'TAK13DDI-26113D Trial Design.xlsm', 'TAK13DDI-26113D_SDTM_Metadata_2021-02-06T19-09-32.xlsx', 'TAK13DDI_SDTM_DMT_Appendix.xlsx']
```

So `b` is the list you want

Comment: is there a way to remove first empty list?

Comment: `b[1::]` is the way

Comment: Working as you wanted??

Comment: Working awesome.

Comment: Great, happy to help you!

Comment: one problem is i will not know what will be the directory name in that case if i hard code i[6::] will not work.

Comment: You can split every item with `/` as a separator. So all elements after / is what you want. Understood? I am also writing the exact code so wait for few seconds

Comment: `b=[i.split("/")[1] for i in a]` so b[1::] is your required code

Comment: Working as you wanted??